# Прошу оценить реализацию шаблона "Состояние"

Tags: c#, state, design

Передо мной стоит учебная задача применить шаблон State для отчётов в моём групповом проекте.
Для отчёта определено три состояния: создан, утверждён и отправлен. Отчёт может изменяться в состояниях по следующей схеме: создан <-> утверждён -> отправлен.
Проблема заключается в комментариях моего преподавателя к этому решению. Он утверждает, что количество методов в каждом классе избыточно и что можно обойтись одним методом в каждом. Я считаю, что текущее решение является классическим вариантом, и я не понимаю в чём заключается проблема, поэтому решил вынести этот вопрос сюда. Пожалуйста, дайте ваши комментарии по поводу этого решения и возможные пути его улучшения.

#### Интерфейс состояния и классы состояний

```
     public interface IReportState
     {
         DateTime Date { get; set; }
    
         User Changer { get; set; }
    
         string Name { get; }   
    
         void Approve(Report report, DateTime date, User user);
    
         void Send(Report report, DateTime date, User user);
    
         void Cancel(Report report, DateTime date, User user);
     }

    public class CreatedState : IReportState
    {
        ...
    
        public void Approve(Report report, DateTime date, User user) =>
            report.State = new ApprovedState(date, user);
    
        public void Cancel(Report report, DateTime date, User user) =>
            throw new IncorrectChangeReportStateException("You cannot cancel not approved report!");
    
        public void Send(Report report, DateTime date, User user) =>
            throw new IncorrectChangeReportStateException("You cannot send not approved report!");
    }

     public class ApprovedState : IReportState
     {
         ...  
    
         public void Approve(Report report, DateTime date, User user)
         {
             return;
         }
    
         public void Cancel(Report report, DateTime date, User user) =>
             report.State = new CreatedState(date, user);
    
         public void Send(Report report, DateTime date, User user) =>
             report.State = new SentState(date, user);
     }

    public class SentState : IReportState
    {
        ...
    
        public void Approve(Report report, DateTime date, User user) =>
            throw new IncorrectChangeReportStateException("This report has been sent already!");
    
        public void Cancel(Report report, DateTime date, User user) =>
            throw new IncorrectChangeReportStateException("This report has been sent already!");
    
        public void Send(Report report, DateTime date, User user)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

#### Класс отчёта

```
    public class Report
    {
        IReportState State { get; set; }

        ...        
    
        public void Approve(DateTime date, User user) =>
            State.Approve(this, date, user);
    
        public void Send(DateTime date, User user) =>
            State.Send(this, date, user);
    
        public void Cancel(DateTime date, User user) =>
            State.Cancel(this, date, user);
    }
```

Comment: ну видимо, если существует строгая последовательность, то имеется в виду что-то типа такого: https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Behavioral/State/README.html

Comment: Ну и добавлять, например, в состояние "approved" метод "cancel" или в состояние "create" метод "Approve"  (и т.д.)  крайне странно

Comment: *"дайте ваши комментарии по поводу этого решения и возможные пути его улучшения."* --- я считаю, что все комментарии должен давать именно недовольный преподаватель, а вы должны всячески ЕГО докапывать.  А советов тут могут надавать сотню, которые, точно так же, не удовлетворят преподавателя...... зачем эта вся канитель вокруг - не ясно. Если источник под боком

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, благодарю за ссылку. Не понимаю почему Вы находите это решение странным. Когда я писал этот код, я предполагал, что состояния будут брать на себя ответственность по обработке запросов к отчёту, поэтому нормально, что каждое состояние обрабатывает все запросы. По поводу преподавателя согласен, но вопрос вынес на обсуждение, чтобы узнать что-то новое от более опытных людей, а не чтобы найти путь удовлетворить преподавателя.

Comment: *"Не понимаю почему Вы находите это решение странным."* --- ну давайте логически размышлять. В каждом из представленных в текущем коде состояний, можно использовать только один метод, остальные, по факту, выбрасывают исключения или заполнены заглушкой (считаем тоже их нерабочими).... В итоге, рабочий метод, который выполнит действие, всегда только один....¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ... Что тут ещё обсуждать?)) Если докрутить, то можно назвать метод `execute`, а от остальных смело избавляться. Добавить метод, как в ссылке выше например (setNextState) и в конце `execute` делать переход к другому состоянию

Comment: В даннрм примере вижу что такок решение не удобно сопровождать (например добавить еще одно состояние). И в вашем примере пока нет возможности узнать текущее состояние (рефлексия не в счет)